# Error in reading coordinates in GRASS module in QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting, grass-7.0

I am trying to split some lines using points as described here:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-split-a-line-using-points-td4981464.html

When I run the comands:

```
v.out.ascii <my points> out=points.txt
while read x y; do
    v.edit <my lines> tool=break coords=$x,$y cat=0-99999
done < points.txt
```

I get the following Error message:

```
ERROR: Option <coords> must be provided in multiples of 2
    You provided 1 item(s): 2911816.37852443|2182783.62147557|182,,
```